# Discover multicast addresses in a network

Tags: networking, streaming, multicast, igmp

Consider there is a network where users can access multicast streams by knowing the IP and port of the multicast streams. The traffic is not sent to them by default till they request the stream and if the user doesn't know the addresses he/she cannot access the streams. Is there any way to detect these addresses and access the multicast streams?

Comment: I'd guess no, but it should be possible to bruteforce the whole list.

Comment: @grawity: Do you know any special tool? Can you estimate how long it may last? I guess it may last very long time.

Comment: There's some ways to get forward here, but there are not a generic solution to get all the available multicast streams. SAP is a protocol sort of aiming to solve what you've asked for but I would say it's rarely used.

When I'm in this situation I look for IGMP and PIM traffic on the network which gives clues to which groups are used. If there are no, a brute force search is possible to do, a simplistic tool for that is done quite easily.

Comment: @Intenso: Finally I decided to brute force the network by sending IGMP requests to all possible multicast groups (e.g all multicast IP range); simultaneously I started another thread to probe the received multicast traffic; and by investigating this packets I could detects multicast streams in the network.